# How to extend Azure Custom script extension default timeout?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to run a script on Azure VM using Customer script extension, the script has a command that import the database to SQL Server installed on Azure VM, which takes more than 90 minutes, and the extension execution gets ended after 90 minutes.

I want to know if there is any way to get it extended.

I have a workaround to run a script in Runonce that will trigger the script after first login but I dont want to give end users this experience where they need wait until the operation succeeds and this approach is error prone as users may cancel this operation.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just fire off the and don't wait for completion. But maybe you're better of switching to Azure SQL.